# Given that $\gcd(a,2)=2$ and $\gcd(b,4)=2$, prove that $\gcd(a+b, 4)=4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $\gcd(a,2)=2$ and $\gcd(b,4)=2$, prove that $\gcd(a+b, 4)=4$

$\gcd(a,2)=2\implies 2\mid a\implies a=2q_1$ for some $q_1\in \mathbb Z$

$\gcd(b,4)=2\implies 2\mid b\implies b=2q_2$ for some $q_2\in \mathbb Z$

$a+b=2(q_1+q_2)$. How can I show $\gcd(a+b, 4)=4$?

Comment: What happens when $a=4$ and $b=2$?

Comment: Note that you also know $q_2 \notin 2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Your question has an error in text: $gcd(a,4)=2$ is correct!!!

Answer (score 2):

Take $a=8$ and $b=2$. Then $\gcd(a,2)=2$ and $\gcd(b,4)=2$, but $\gcd(a+b,4)=\gcd(10,4)=2$. So it is not true.

Answer (score 1):

All you can show is that $\gcd(a+b, 4) \in \{2,4\}$ because $q_1$ has not enough restrictions.
If you had $\gcd(a,{\color{red}{4}}) = 2$ you would be able to prove that
$$a+b = 2((2n+1) + (2m+1)) = 4(n+m+1)$$
so $\gcd(a+b, 4) = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

As Dietrich Burde pointed out, the statement you're trying to prove is false. Here's some stuff anyway.

---

$\gcd(a,2)=2$ just means that $a$ is even, or $$a \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$$

$\gcd(b,4)=2$ means that $b$ is even but not a multiple of four, or $$b \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$$

Since $a$ is even, $a$ can leave a remainder of $0$ or $2$ when divided by $4$.

---

**Case 1**: $a \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$

In this case, $a+b \equiv 2 + 0 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$. This means that $4$ doesn't divide $a+b$, so clearly $\gcd(a+b, 4) \neq 4$. In fact, $$\gcd(a+b,4)=2$$

**Case 2**: $a \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$

In this case, $a+b \equiv 2 + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. This means that $4$ does divide $a+b$, so $$\gcd(a+b, 4) = 4$$